# why TensorFlow LSTM RNN fails to predict a target even if data contains it?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have a time series DS containing ~800k time steps.

I am trying to train a simple LSTM RNN using TensorFlow/Keras.

After several unsuccessful tries to predict any useful (meaningful) target I decided to to see will it be able to predict the target which the source data already contains.

And unfortunately it failed.

I do the following:

```py
# required imports
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras.layers as tf_layers
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model, Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import MAPE, MSE
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping, ReduceLROnPlateau
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing import timeseries_dataset_from_array
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

print(df_src.shape)
# >>> (833231, 19)
```

First of all I have scaled whole DS

```py
mms = MinMaxScaler()
temp = df_src.drop(columns=['time'])
df = mms.fit_transform(temp)
df = pd.DataFrame(df, index=df_src.index, columns=temp.columns)
print(df.shape)
# >>> (833231, 18)
```

for the sake of simplicity of the example, I scaled the entire dataset, despite the fact that in real life it would be more reasonable to scale the training, validation and test datasets separately

I have used one of columns as target:

```py
df['target'] = df[df.columns[3]]
```

then I have created a sliding-window datasets for training, validating and testing:

```py
TEST_FRAC = 0.15
WINDOW_SIZE = 200
test_size = int(len(df) * TEST_FRAC)
train_size = len(df) - 2 * test_size

X = df.drop(columns=['target'])
y = df['target'].shift(1 - WINDOW_SIZE) 
# shift is required because 'timeseries_dataset_from_array' takes 
# targets from the head of window, not from the tail

ds_train = timeseries_dataset_from_array(X, y, 
                                         sequence_length=WINDOW_SIZE, 
                                         end_index=train_size)
ds_val = timeseries_dataset_from_array(X, y, 
                                       sequence_length=WINDOW_SIZE, 
                                       start_index=train_size, 
                                       end_index=train_size+test_size)
ds_test = timeseries_dataset_from_array(X, y, 
                                        sequence_length=WINDOW_SIZE,
                                        start_index=train_size+test_size)
```

Then I check if the target is really included into datasets as I've expected:

```py
for idx, batch in enumerate(ds_train):
    x, y = batch
    test = x[:,-1,3] 
    # takes all last values from target column from every window 
    # those are supposed to be equal to target values
    if not np.array_equal(test, y):
        print(f'wrong target at {idx}')
# >>>
```

this code outputs nothing, so target is 100% included into the data.

then I create the model:

```py
def create_model_v1(input_shape, 
                    rnn_units=128, 
                    classifier_units=64, 
                    dropout_rate=None,
                    learning_rate=1e-2):
    inputs = tf_layers.Input(shape=input_shape)
    x = tf_layers.LSTM(units=rnn_units)(inputs)
        
    if dropout_rate is not None:
        x = tf_layers.Dropout(dropout_rate)(x)
        
    x = tf_layers.Dense(classifier_units, activation='relu')(x)

    if dropout_rate is not None:
        x = tf_layers.Dropout(dropout_rate)(x)

    x = tf_layers.Dense(outputs)(x)
    md = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=x)

    md.compile(loss='MSE',
               optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=learning_rate),
               metrics==['MAPE'])
    return md


md1 = create_model_v1(input_shape=(WINDOW_SIZE, (df.shape[1] - 1)),
                      dropout_rate=0.2)
md1.summary()
```

And as expected the output is:

```
Model: "model"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 input_1 (InputLayer)        [(None, 200, 18)]         0         
                                                                 
 lstm (LSTM)                 (None, 128)               75264     
                                                                 
 dropout (Dropout)           (None, 128)               0         
                                                                 
 dense (Dense)               (None, 64)                8256      
                                                                 
 dropout_1 (Dropout)         (None, 64)                0         
                                                                 
 dense_1 (Dense)             (None, 1)                 65        
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 83,585
Trainable params: 83,585
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Finally, I train the model:

```py
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('./save/md1.hdf5', 
                             verbose=0,
                             save_best_only=True)
earlystop = EarlyStopping(patience=25, 
                          restore_best_weights=True)
callbacks_list = [checkpoint, earlystop]

history = md1.fit(ds_train,
                  validation_data = ds_val, 
                  epochs = 200,
                  callbacks = callbacks_list,
                  verbose=1
                 )
```

I am expecting `MAPE` to go close to `0` but it does not:

```
Epoch 1/200
4556/4556 [==============================] - 59s 13ms/step - loss: 0.0021 - MAPE: 5.0266 - val_loss: 0.0078 - val_MAPE: 18.2009
Epoch 2/200
4556/4556 [==============================] - 58s 13ms/step - loss: 8.4463e-04 - MAPE: 4.2501 - val_loss: 0.0080 - val_MAPE: 18.5296
Epoch 3/200
4556/4556 [==============================] - 58s 13ms/step - loss: 9.3098e-04 - MAPE: 4.4582 - val_loss: 0.0079 - val_MAPE: 18.4074
Epoch 4/200
4556/4556 [==============================] - 58s 13ms/step - loss: 8.6505e-04 - MAPE: 4.2846 - val_loss: 0.0080 - val_MAPE: 18.4482
Epoch 5/200
4556/4556 [==============================] - 58s 13ms/step - loss: 9.4212e-04 - MAPE: 4.4958 - val_loss: 0.0079 - val_MAPE: 18.3962
...
Epoch 25/200
4556/4556 [==============================] - 58s 13ms/step - loss: 9.4219e-04 - MAPE: 4.4964 - val_loss: 0.0079 - val_MAPE: 18.3953
Epoch 26/200
4556/4556 [==============================] - 58s 13ms/step - loss: 9.4219e-04 - MAPE: 4.4964 - val_loss: 0.0079 - val_MAPE: 18.3953
```

validation `MAPE` is `~18%` which is pretty bad

the distribution of the real target and a prediction shows that this NN learns nothing

```py
md1.load_weights('./save/md1.hdf5')
y_pred = md1.predict(ds_test, verbose=1)

sns.histplot(y_pred, bins=30, color='r')
sns.histplot(df['target'].iloc[(train_size+test_size):], bins=30, color='b')
```

and it draws the [following distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icc82.png)
that means two things:

1. RNN really learns nothing
2. RNN outputs almost the same result regardless of the input

Why this is happening? That did I wrong in this example?

Comment: there are tons of things that can go wrong, that `1e-2` learning rate is very big, then you have vanishing and exploding gradient and more

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia, thank you for your suggestion. I have tried LR from `1e-2` to `1e-6`, I even used `ReduceLROnPlateau` callback to play with LR, this is the most stable result which I have got.